# Android Management API: How to prevent any password to be set?

Tags: android, google-apis-explorer, android-management-api

Is there any way to prevent any security level (password, fingerprint, face id) to be set by a user? I've expected all the possibly related properties such as *passwordPolicies*, *keyguardDisabled* (**true**), *keyguardDisabledFeatures* (**ALL_FEATURES**), but prevented only the fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to prevent the user from setting a password on Android, whether you're using the Android Management API or DevicePolicyManager.

However you could:

1. Monitor when the user sets a password by calling [`enterprises.devices.get`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get) and checking the field [`Device.deviceSettings.isDeviceSecure`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#DeviceSettings).
2. When there is a password, remove it by issuing a [`RESET_PASSWORD`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/issueCommand#CommandType) command and do not set the `Command.newPassword` field.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's too unreliable.